# Catching ids and its values from a string with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I was wondering how can I create `preg_match` for catching:

```
id=4
```

`4` being any number and how can I search for the above example in a string?

If this is could be correct `/^id=[0-9]/`, the reason why I'm asking is because I'm not really good with `preg_match`.

Comment: What if you try first, then ask?

Comment: `preg_match('/^id=(\d+)/', $yourString, $matches); var_dump($matches[1]);`

Comment: it's already clear, my connection was too slow to digest other comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for 4 being any number, we must set the range for it:

```
/^id\=[0-9]+/
```

`\`escape the equal-sign, plus after the number means 1 or even more.

Comment: You don't have to escape `\\` really

Comment: @user2865738 Actually, it will not grab a number but result will be numerical string if you cast it to int it will be limited either to `(2^32) / 2 - 1` or `(2^64) / 2 - 1` number, depending you use 32 bit or 64 bit system, respectively.

Comment: @Ilia Rostovtsev you are right, i confused just now. and `\d` can instead `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with the the following:

```
/id=(\d+)/g
```

#### Explanations:

- `id=` - Literal `id=`
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group `0-9` a character range between `0` and `9`; `+` - repeating infinite times
- `/g` - modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

[Example online](http://regex101.com/r/hZ8lT4)

If you want to grab all ids and its values in PHP you could go with:

```
$string = "There are three ids: id=10 and id=12 and id=100";
preg_match_all("/id=(\d+)/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => id=10
            [1] => id=12
            [2] => id=100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 100
        )

)
```

[Example online](http://ideone.com/eBztpD)

**Note:** If you want to match all you must use `/g` modifier. PHP doesn't support it but has other function for that which is [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). All you need to do is remove the `g` from the regex.